# AP also acting as server in a local network?

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I'm looking to create a portable media server also acting as a AP. For this I use a NUC. I got an AP running using **hostapd** and a DNS server fine. However I seem to be unable to connect to the media server running on the same machine. I'm guessing the AP isn't giving access to a local network.

How can I include the AP (or more correctly, the machine running the AP) to also be part of the same network as connected devices?

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm doing it on Ubuntu Server. But yes, it applies to more flavors of *nix I suppose @Pilot6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out hostapd service is not started in correct order on boot. After shuffling everything around it is working as intended.